# RequireJS - Issues loading Jquery and Jquery UI plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

im new to requirejs and been loving it so far. I am in the process of implementing it to my existing project. I have a few jquery, Jquery UI and bootstrap plugins that all need to initialise at the start of the app.

I was hoping to put them all ligned up in a file called GDI_common.js and have it set in my main.js file in a require. When I load my page it seems to ignore my GDI_commons script. If I try to manually load the plugins via console they work fine.

I made sure that my dependencies are all correct and have what they need. Not quite sure what im overlooking at this point. Would anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

This is what my main.js file looks like:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jqueryui": "../assets/jqueryUI/jquery-ui.min",
        "bootstrap": "bootstrap.min",
        "bootstrap_select": "../assets/silviomoreto-bootstrap-select-a8ed49e/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min",
        "jqueryui_timepicker": "jquery-ui-timepicker-addon",
        "jqueryui_timepicker_ext":  "jquery-ui-sliderAccess",
        "moment": "moment",
        "cookie": "js.cookie",
        "knockout-amd-helpers": "knockout-amd-helpers.min",
        "text": "text"
    },
        "shim": {
        bootstrap: {
            deps : [ 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Bootstrap'
        },
        bootstrap_select: {
            deps : [ 'jquery', 'bootstrap'],
            exports: 'Bootstrap_Select'
        },      
        jqueryui_timepicker: {
            deps : [ 'jquery','jqueryui'],
            exports: 'JqueryUI_Timepicker'
        },
        jqueryui_timepicker_ext: {
            deps : [ 'jquery','jqueryui'],
            exports: 'Jqueryui_Timepicker_Ext'
        }   
    }
});

require(["jquery","knockout", "XApplication", "Xcommon", "XButtons", "knockout-amd-helpers", "text", "moment"], function ($, ko, XApplication, GDI_common) {
ko.amdTemplateEngine.defaultPath = "../templates";

 var viewmodel = new GDI_Application();
 ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
 viewmodel.fetchdata();

});
```

This is what my my GDI_common file looks like:

```
define(["jquery", "jqueryui", "jqueryui_timepicker", "jqueryui_timepicker_ext", "moment", "bootstrap_select"], function($) {
    //This loads the jqueryui_timepicker (jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js) it needs jqueryui.
    $('input[title^="Date de"]').datetimepicker({
        addSliderAccess: true,
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });

    //This loads the bootstrap-select plugin (bootstrap-select.min.js) it needs jquery and bootstrap.
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

    //This is a jquery custom code that is used to calculate 2 fields upon clicking the .donne_moi_le_temps button.
    $(".donne_moi_le_temps").click(function(){
        updateDuration($('#DateDeDébut').val(), $('#DateDeFin').val());

        function updateDuration(startTime, endTime) {
            var ms = moment(endTime, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm').diff(moment(startTime, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm')),
            dt = moment.duration(ms),
            h = Math.floor(dt.asHours()),
            m = moment.utc(ms).format('mm');

            $('input[title^="Dur"]').val(h + ' heures, ' + m + ' minutes');
        }
    });

    //This is loads the bootstrap tooltip function, this requires jquery and bootstrap.
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    //This is custom code and depends on the tooltip to be loaded first.
    $(document).on('mouseenter', ".over_flow_control", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if(this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth && !$this.attr('title')) {
            $this.tooltip({
            title: $this.text(),
            placement: "bottom",
            container: 'body'
        });
            $this.tooltip('show');
        }
    });     
});
```

Comment: The config doesn't look good to me. It missed `jquery` and `knockout` (unless these are root level modules, or configuration is set up in some other place). And another gotcha is about jqueryui minified source, just make sure it is amd compatible.

Comment: Yeah i left out jquery and knockout as they are at the root level. I'm gonna look into the jqueryui min amd compatible version and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, you can use [commonjs style](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) with requirejs now. Not an issue, but something you may consider to arguably simplify code.

Comment: Ok thanks ill check that out.

Comment: Try creating a shim for jqueryui. Also would be good if you post the error you are getting.

Comment: You say "it seems to ignore my GDI_commons script" What makes you say this? What do you expect to happen but does not happen? Is there an error on the console? You also say "If I try to manually load the plugins via console they work fine." How do you load them at the console? Please edit your question with the answers to what I'm asking in this comment.